# xpath: searching a node in a html table row (multiple conditions)

Tags: xpath, parent, nodes, siblings

## Looking for a xpath node whose table row must fulfill several conditions

Searching for those node "col_functions" whose table row values is "John Wayne" from the table @class="table_list".

("col_functions", "col_firstname" and "col_lastname are sibling nodes and childs from the table)

```
    <table class="table_list">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="col_firstname">John</td>
           <td class="col_lastname">Lennon</td>
           <td class="col_functions"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="col_firstname">John</td>
           <td class="col_lastname">Wayne</td> 
           <td class="col_functions"></td> <=== looking for this node!!
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="col_firstname">Wayne</td>
           <td class="col_lastname">John</td>
           <td class="col_functions"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to check for class names all over the place:

```
//table[@class="table_list"]//tr[td[@class="col_firstname"] = "John" and td[@class="col_lastname"] = "Wayne"]/td[@class="col_functions"]/text()
```

Here we are basically checking all rows inside the `table` for cells with first name `John` and last name `Wayne`, getting the cell with `col_functions` as an output.

Answer (score 1):

Using siblings it will be like that:

```
//table[@class='table_list']//td[@class='col_firstname'][text()='John']/following-sibling::td[@class='col_lastname'][text=()'Wayne']/following-sibling::td[@class='col_functions']
```